# Beautifulsoup - Remove HTML tags

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to strip away all the HTML tags from the ‘profile’ soup, whoever am I unable to perform the “.text.strip()” operation as it is a list, as shown in code below

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint 

page = requests.get("https://web.archive.org/web/20121007172955/http://www.nga.gov/collection/anZ1.htm").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(company_page, "html.parser")

info = {}
info['Profile'] = soup.select('div.text-desc-members')

pprint(info)
```

Comment: _unable to perform the “.text.strip()” operation as it is a list_ Problem solved then, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate through that list:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint 

page = requests.get("https://web.archive.org/web/20121007172955/http://www.nga.gov/collection/anZ1.htm").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

info = {}
info['Profile'] = soup.select('div.text-desc-members')


for item in info['Profile']:
    pprint(item.text.strip())
```

Comment: are you there @chitown88

Comment: pay attention for that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381310/how-to-get-dynamic-data-from-this-website-in-pandas/59381628?noredirect=1#comment104957409_59381628